# catchall method on react router with express server breaks static assets

Tags: react-router-v4

I followed the [catch-all route handling advice here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/) and doing so now breaks access to my other static assets that I serve using express.static in my public folder, such as bundle.js and my css files.  I was wondering how to address this.  I get this error in my console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and when trying to open `localhost:3000/bundle.js` from my browser, I'm just redirected to index.html, as I suppose is expected. My express server is set up as follows:

I'm wondering how the advice on that site can be considered a solution when React Router itself relies on `bundle.js` being loaded in an environment that uses webpack, which is way too common for it not to be addressed.  Will thhe only workaround to this be making separate routes for all my static assets?  I don't think that that would be all that scalable, especially if I have hundreds of images that I'd be serving.  Thanks.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();


app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/index.html"), err => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(8080, _ => console.log("listening on 8080"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `app.use(express.static("public"));` above your catch-all route.